# How do I get args passed to this scala object?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to figure out how to pass args to this scala object:

I have this class written in this sbt project path: `allaboutscala/src/main/scala/gzip_practice/gzipwriter`

```
package gzip_practice

import java.io._
import java.util.zip._

/** Gzcat
    */
object gzcat extends App {
    private val buf = new Array[Byte](1024)

    try {
        for (path <- args) {
            try {
                var in = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(path))
                var n = in.read(buf)
                while (n >= 0) {
                    System.out.write(buf, 0, n)
                    n = in.read(buf)
                }
            }
            catch {
                case _:FileNotFoundException =>
                    System.err.printf("File Not Found: %s", path)
                case _:SecurityException =>
                    System.err.printf("Permission Denied: %s", path)
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        System.out.flush
    }
}
```

This is an sbt project called `allaboutscala`. I am trying to run it with:
`scala src/main/scala/gzip_practice/gzipwriter.scala "hi"` but the command just hangs and I don't know why.

How am I supposed to run this object constructor with args?

Comment: If you define a method within the object, you can invoke it with `gzcat.func(arg1, arg2)` etc.

Comment: but this is just a constructor here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `scala` command as a script runner.

Normally, it will wrap your "script" code in a main method.

But if you have an object with a main method, like your `App`, it will use that for the entry point.

However, it doesn't like `package` statements in the script.

If you comment out your `package` statement, you can compile and run with:

```
scala -nc somefile.scala myarg.gz
```

`-nc` means "no compile daemon"; otherwise, it will start a second process to compile scripts, so that subsequent compiles go faster; but it is a brittle workflow and I don't recommend it.
I confirmed that your code works.

Usually, folks use sbt or an IDE to compile and package in a jar to run with `scala myapp.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

An `object` is a static instance of a class. You could construct it using:

```
object gzcat(args: String*) extends App {
  ...
}
```

`args` is bound as a `val` within the object `gzcat`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run it with repl? I would suggest running it with sbt, then you can run sbt projects from project root directory with command line parameter as follows:

```
sbt "run file1.txt file2.txt"
```

The quotes are required. If you leave sbt shell open, then it running it will be much faster. Open shell in project root with

```
sbt
```

In the sbt shell:

```
run file1.txt file2.txt
```

Within the sbt shell, no quotes.

Comment: This answer would be more correct if you said what path is required for the args. Are they relative to build.sbt?